# Weird eslint error "Parsing error: Unexpected token = (Fatal)"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, eslint

I'm trying to setup auth0 on a react app and this error keeps popping up on my `auth0= new auth0.WebAuth({` initializtion, I'm trying to disable eslint with `/* eslint-disable */` but it's not working.

This is my Auth.js file:

```
// imports EventEmitter
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';
// imports the Auth0 JS library
import auth0 from 'auth0-js';
// imports Auth0 credentials from the auth0-variables.js file
import { AUTH_CONFIG } from './auth0-variables';
// imports the history module, which will be created later
import history from '../history';

export default class Auth extends EventEmitter {
    // An instance of Auth0 is instantiated with Auth0 credentials gotten from the auth0-variables.js file


    auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({ //this is where I'm getting the error

    domain: AUTH_CONFIG.domain,
    clientID: AUTH_CONFIG.clientId,
    redirectUri: AUTH_CONFIG.callbackUrl,
    audience: `https://${AUTH_CONFIG.domain}/userinfo`,

    // Telling Auth0 what to return after a successful authentication, in this case, the token and the id_token
    responseType: 'token id_token',

    // To retrieve a user's profile after authentication, we need to add openid profile to the the scope.
    scope: 'openid profile'
  });
```

This is my .eslint:

```
{
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:import/errors",
    "plugin:import/warnings"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "react"
  ],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
       "jsx": true,
       "modules": true,
       "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true
    }
  },
  "env": {
    "es6": true,
    "browser": true,
    "node": true,
    "jquery": true,
    "mocha": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "no-unexpected-multiline": "warn",
    "comma-dangle": 0,
    "quotes": 0,
    "no-console": 1,
    "no-debugger": 1,
    "no-var": 1,
    "semi": [1, "always"],
    "no-trailing-spaces": 0,
    "eol-last": 0,
    "no-unused-vars": 0,
    "no-underscore-dangle": 0,
    "no-alert": 0,
    "no-lone-blocks": 0,
    "jsx-quotes": 1,
    "react/display-name": [ 1, {"ignoreTranspilerName": false }],
    "react/forbid-prop-types": [1, {"forbid": ["any"]}],
    "react/jsx-boolean-value": 1,
    "react/jsx-closing-bracket-location": 0,
    "react/jsx-curly-spacing": 1,
    "react/jsx-indent-props": 0,
    "react/jsx-key": 1,
    "react/jsx-max-props-per-line": 0,
    "react/jsx-no-bind": 1,
    "react/jsx-no-duplicate-props": 1,
    "react/jsx-no-literals": 0,
    "react/jsx-no-undef": 1,
    "react/jsx-pascal-case": 1,
    "react/jsx-sort-prop-types": 0,
    "react/jsx-sort-props": 0,
    "react/jsx-uses-react": 1,
    "react/jsx-uses-vars": 1,
    "react/no-danger": 1,
    "react/no-did-mount-set-state": 1,
    "react/no-did-update-set-state": 1,
    "react/no-direct-mutation-state": 1,
    "react/no-multi-comp": 1,
    "react/no-set-state": 0,
    "react/no-unknown-property": 1,
    "react/prefer-es6-class": 1,
    "react/prop-types": 1,
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": 1,
    "react/require-extension": 1,
    "react/self-closing-comp": 1,
    "react/sort-comp": 1,
    "react/wrap-multilines": 1
  },
}
```

and this is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "TurboWeb",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "prestart": "babel-node tools/startMessage.js",
    "start": "npm-run-all --parallel open:src lint:watch test:watch",
    "open:src": "babel-node tools/srcServer.js",
    "lint": "node_modules/.bin/esw webpack.config.* src tools",
    "lint:watch": "npm run lint -- --watch",
    "test": "mocha --reporter spec tools/testSetup.js \"src/**/*.test.js\"",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch"
  },
  "author": "Cory House",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "auth0-js": "^9.2.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "6.8.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta.2",
    "events": "^2.0.0",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "jquery": "2.2.3",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.9",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "pusher": "^1.5.1",
    "react": "15.6.2",
    "react-dom": "15.6.2",
    "react-redux": "4.4.5",
    "react-router": "3.2.0",
    "react-router-redux": "4.0.4",
    "redux": "3.5.2",
    "redux-thunk": "2.0.1",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.2.12",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.74.2",
    "toastr": "2.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "6.8.0",
    "babel-core": "6.8.0",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-react-display-name": "2.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react-hmre": "1.1.1",
    "babel-register": "6.8.0",
    "cheerio": "0.22.0",
    "colors": "1.1.2",
    "compression": "1.6.1",
    "cross-env": "1.0.7",
    "css-loader": "0.23.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.0.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-15": "^1.0.5",
    "eslint": "2.10.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "1.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "5.0.1",
    "eslint-watch": "2.1.11",
    "eventsource-polyfill": "0.9.6",
    "expect": "1.19.0",
    "express": "4.13.4",
    "extract-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "jsdom": "8.5.0",
    "mocha": "2.4.5",
    "nock": "8.0.0",
    "npm-run-all": "1.8.0",
    "open": "0.0.5",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "15.0.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "^15.5.0",
    "redux-immutable-state-invariant": "1.2.3",
    "redux-mock-store": "1.0.2",
    "rimraf": "2.5.2",
    "style-loader": "0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "2.0.3",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.10.0"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/coryhouse/pluralsight-redux-starter"
  }
}
```

and my webpack.config just in case:

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import path from 'path';

export default {
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    // noInfo: false,
    entry: [
        'eventsource-polyfill', // necessary for hot reloading with IE
        'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true', //note that it reloads the page if hot module reloading fails.
        './src/index'
    ],
    target: 'web',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist', // Note: Physical files are only output by the production build task `npm run build`.
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: false,
        contentBase: './src'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(), new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
        Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],
        // In case you imported plugins individually, you must also require them here:
        Util: "exports-loader?Util!bootstrap/js/dist/util",
        Dropdown: "exports-loader?Dropdown!bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown"})
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
                loaders: 'babel-loader'
            }, {
                test: /(\.css)$/,
                loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            }, {
                test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                loader: 'file-loader'
            }, {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader'
            }, {
                test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader'
            }, {
                test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader'
            }, {
                test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|svg)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'url-loader',
                        options: {
                            limit: 8000, // Convert images < 8kb to base64 strings
                            name: 'images/[hash]-[name].[ext]'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: Well, that *is* invalid ES6 code. You are using some experimental features with the jsx setting, and you need to configure eslint accordingly

Comment: Thanks for the response! What would be valid es6 code in this case? How do I write it properly to initialize auth0?

Comment: Put `this.auth = …` inside the `constructor() { … }`.

Answer (score 0):

Class instance properties (`auth = new auth0.WebAuth(/*...*/);` inside a class body) are still experimental. You can [follow development of the proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) if you're interested - it's at stage 3 of the [tc39 proposal process](https://tc39.github.io/process-document/) as of this writing.

If you want to use class properties today (I see you're using React, and they're pretty common in React code), and assuming you already have Babel set up, ESLint can parse them and other experimental features with the help of [babel-eslint](https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint). There are more complete instructions on the readme, but you'll want to `npm install --save-dev babel-eslint` and add `"parser": "babel-eslint"` to your `.eslintrc.json`.